# The background image width does not work

Tags: html, css

I have an html file, and I set the background url to an image, but the image does not fill the browser's width:

[image]

I also tried set the `width` property to make it wider, but it seems to have no effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #bg {

            height:1500px;
            background: url("img/timg7.jpg") center top no-repeat;
            width:1800px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body id="bg">

<div style="width:400px; height: 200px; background-color: antiquewhite">
    BLOCK
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You gave your body a width? What's with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `background-size` attribute for this.

Your CSS should be:

```
#bg {

    background: url("img/timg7.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should use **background-size**, there is a [demo](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/background-size/) for background-size.

Try to use:

```
 background-size: 120%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
background-size:  cover;

**and please remove those height and width**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#bg {

     background: url("img/timg7.jpg") center top no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bg{
  background: url("img/timg7.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an id on your `body`, as `document.body` with get it with JavaScript, and you can just use `body` in the CSS. Of course, that's not your issue. See the code below:

```
html,body{
 padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:url(img/timg7.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:cover;
}
```

By the way, you should use external CSS, so it's cached into Browser Memory.